# A topological space that is Hausdorff, Normal, and Lindelöf is metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My guess is "no" but as I tried to approach the problem in an attempt to prove it I couldn't show that these 3 conditions can put me in the conditions to use *Urysohn's metrization theorem*,that is such space has a enumerable basis and is regular.

Comment: [Useful site](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=hausdorff%2Blindel%C3%B6f%2Bnormal%2B~Metrizable) for this kind of questions

Comment: Lindelöf and $T_3$ together already implies Hausdorff and normal. There are plenty of non-metric Lindelöf $T_3$ spaces (even compact ones), like the Double Arrow, Aleksandrov double of $[0,1]$, lexicographically ordered square, large compact products, $\beta \mathbb{N}$ etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; Lindelöf is not the sort of countability condition that is helpful here.  For instance, any compact Hausdorff space satisfies those conditions, so any non-metrizable compact Hausdorff space is a counterexample.  For instance, you could take the 1-point compactification of an uncountable discrete space, or a product $[0,1]^S$ where $S$ is uncountable.

Comment: My job here was to consider a Hausdorff space $X$ and verify the equivalence between $X$ being compact and $X^{n}$ being Lindelöf for any cardinal $n$ ,it was rather clumsy of me not doing so.Thank you

Comment: @AHandsomeAlien If a Hausdorff space $X$ is not compact, it has some infinite closed discrete subspace $M$. A.H. Stone's theorem says that $M^{\aleph_1}$ is not normal (but is regular), and so $X^{\aleph_1}$ cannot be Linfdelöf, as  its closed subspace $M^{\aleph_1}$ would also be Lindelöf which it's not. (it would be regular, as $M$ is, and Lindelöf, but not normal, contradiction). So if a Hausdorff space $X$ has the property that $M^{\aleph_1}$ is Lindelöf, then $X$ is compact.